# How to wrap contents like image, button inside Android layouts?

Tags: android, wpf, android-layout

I want to place list of buttons in a layout and I want them to flow to automatically. Take a look at this picture, This is how [WrapPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.wrappanel?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) wraps its content in WPF. Is there a way I can do this in Android?

[image: This is what WrapPanel does in WPF]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC163252.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a linearlayout in android which allows to layout childs in either vertical or horizontal order. You put the buttons inside the linearlayout.

You should go through this [tuorial](http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/) on android layouts. AbsoluteLayout in the link is depracated.

My knowledge of wrap panel is purely based on the link you attached as I haven't worked with WPF.
This is from what i understood.
Android doesn't have a wrap panel layout where child views break to next line when there is less space. Your options are

- to use scrollviews to scroll if the views are bigger than the screen.
- Use the layout_weight property for childs views in a linearlayout. This will make the views to
  resize itself to changing sizes.
- Create a custom layout by extending the ViewGroup class where you measure the child views and decide their position based on the available screen width.

The first 2 options are not exactly what you want. They are alternative approaches with what android provides. But if you want exact thing, you need to make it yourself.

Comment: -1 LinearLayout wont wrap the content. It will just put them in next to each other. If it runs out of space, it wont do anything.

Comment: First of all you are updating your answer and putting minus votes for everyone who is not giving an exact answer. If you want your layouts to be visibile even when it bigger than the screen, you put the linearlayout in a scrollview. There are limitations to android layouts and everything you do in wpf may not be possible. I strongly recomend you first test with all the layouts and understand how they all work together.

Comment: blessenm's right. you must read the Android Common Layout Objects (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html).. and understand how they work together.. :)

Comment: I already have, I couldn't do it, that's the reason I posted here.

Comment: LinearLayout in Android is equivalent to StackPanel in Windows XAML. And according to the Answer below of @Master of None, that ReletivePanel will work instead of LinearLayout and RelativePanel is much faster in performance than other Layoutouts, No doubt, but still how it be possible to put the data in code behind in runtime and the data is almost more than 100 items (pics), so then it may be much difficult to handle.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

For more info on using XML layouts in Android, see this good introduction on the android Developer site:http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Comment: -1 LinearLayout wont wrap the content. It will just put them in next to each other. If it runs out of space, it wont do anything.

Comment: Thanks for updating your image. The code above would create what you first said. But on a mobile device you do not have the case common on desktops of resizing windows. So there is little need for a fluid layout. A better user experience would be to use a linear layout in which all buttons are given equal prominence.

Comment: I just updated the image not my question. Question is same as it was.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to use RelativeLayout in order to achieve that easily.

here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"
    >
<Button 
    android:text="Button" 
    android:id="@+id/button3" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
    >
   <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
    </Button>
   <Button 
       android:text="Button" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:id="@+id/button1" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_weight="2">
   </Button>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout01" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:weightSum="3"
    >
    <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps! ;)

Comment: Nope, You are hacking it. I wanted it to flow automatically, We can do this with LinearLayout also.

Comment: RelativePanel is much faster in performance than other Layoutouts, No doubt, but how it be possible to put the data in code behind in runtime and the data is almost more than 100 items (pics), so then it may be much difficult to handle.

WrapePanel is available in Windows XAML, so I need the functionality like this.